# Function behaving differently in mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function that behaves incorrectly when passed through the mutate function from the dplyr package. The function takes a UK postcode and returns a postal area. It works fine with individual post codes or vectors of postcodes.

Here is the function:

```
pArea_parse <- function(x) {
z <- any(grep('[A-Z][A-Z]',substr(x,1,2)))
y <- any(grep('[A-Z][0-9]',substr(x,1,2)))

if (z) {
    return(substr(x,1,2))
    }
else if (y) {
        return(substr(x,1,1))
        }
else if (!y & !z) {
    return(NA)
        }
}
```

It works:

```
x <- "B30 1AA" # plucked randomly from a postcode site
> pArea_parse(x)
[1] "B"
```

Here is some sample data:

```
test <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), post_code = c("B30 1AA", "B30 3FT", "B30 
3AZ", "BA1 8TU"))
```

Here is my dplyr code:

```
test %>% mutate(postal_area = pArea_parse(post_code))
```

Instead of returning the first letter when there is a letter followed by a number, it returns the letter and the number, even though this doesn't happen with a vector of postcodes or an individual postcode.

```
id post_code postal_area
1   B30 1AA          B3
2   B30 3FT          B3
3   B30 3AZ          B3
4   BA1 8TU          BA
```

How can a function do something it's not programmed to do when used in conjunction with mutate? I am stumped!

Comment: I think the issue is that your function does not work correctly with vectors.

Comment: I think you probably wanted to structure this around ifelse, or even better case_when rather than a traditional if/else clause. The former are vectorized.

Comment: How does one properly vectorize a function? Why would not vectorizing my function produce the observed behvaiour? Thanks.

Comment: If you use `purrr::map` with your function and `tidyr::unnest`, you could avoid vectorizing. `test %>% mutate(postal_area = map(post_code, pArea_parse)) %>% unnest()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `any()` and `if/else` makes your function non-vectorized. That is, if you pass in a vector of values, you do not get the right vector of values out. 
This is not specific to `mutate()`. If you try your function outside of mutate,, you'll get the same result

```
pArea_parse(c("B30 1AA", "B30 3FT", "B30 3AZ", "BA1 8TU"))
# [1] "B3" "B3" "B3" "BA"
```

You can make this easier using the `dplyr` helper function `case_when`. For example

```
pArea_parse <- function(x) {
  z <- grepl('[A-Z][A-Z]',substr(x,1,2))
  y <- grepl('[A-Z][0-9]',substr(x,1,2))

  case_when(z~substr(x,1,2),
            y~substr(x,1,1),
            TRUE~NA_character_)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Do you know where I could learn about vectorizing functions? I don't really understand why my function didn't work and yours did...

Comment: This is the first thing that came up when i googled it: http://alyssafrazee.com/2014/01/29/vectorization.html. There are plenty of others out there as well. Try searching "r vectorize functions"

Comment: Similar answer, but in base R: `pArea_parse <- function(x) {
  z <- grepl('[A-Z][A-Z]',substr(x,1,2))
  y <- grepl('[A-Z][0-9]',substr(x,1,2))
  
  pArea <- as.character(x)
  pArea[z] <- substr(pArea[z],1,2)
  pArea[y] <- substr(pArea[y],1,1)
  pArea[!y & !z] <- NA
  return(pArea)
}`